# Line break for invoice comment in magento

Tags: magento

in magento while sending invoice email the invoice comment showing in same line. The line break was not taking. Please anyone help me to add line break in invoice comment.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193901/magento-order-comment-update-notify-customer-email-formatting-issue/30193989#30193989