# Magento Order comment update - Notify customer email formatting issue

Tags: php, email, magento

This is my first post on the forums, i've been lurking forever now. About time to say hello! I did use the search, but either nobody else has this specific issue, or they don't utilize the comment section the way we do.

We like to send updates to customers through the order comment section of the order page. The email that is sent does not hold any of the line breaks that were used in the original comment. If you have 5 separate sentences, the email shows one big paragraph.

This is really annoying, because our message becomes a big mess. We have to give the customer a series of information about their order, and instructions on how to process with the issue on hand.
Here's two images of what i'm talking about

I have images but I can't post them because I need 10 rep. hmm..

[image: Screenshot of order]

[image: Email alert screenshot]

As you can see, this is just an example and not a long comment, But our regular emails can have a lot of information, and maybe some up-selling.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself, but [David Manners' answer on this question on the Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59584/magento-email-template-format-for-contact-page-comment-text-area-field) sounds promising.

Basically he suggests running the comments through nl2br to convert the newlines to 
 tags that would render in HTML email, like this:

```
{{var data.comment:escape|nl2br}}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks a lot for the link!
I tried it out until I realized that link was discussing a different file. No worries though because it's the right technique required.

Comment: ehh still getting use to commenting.. 


I edited the order_update.html and order_update_guest.html
It was a little different from the suggestion, but basically the same thing. 
I changed: 
{{var comment}} (to) {{var comment|nl2br}}

This allows my order update comments to maintain line breaks and paragraphs!

Thanks again!